# Connected components of $X = L_1 \cup L_{-1} \cup (\bigcup_{n\geq 1}R_n)$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $L_1$ be the line $y=1$, $L_{-1}$ be the line $y=-1$, and for every $n \geq 1$, $R_n$ be the rectangle $R_n = (\{-n,n\}\times[-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}])\cup([-n,n]\times\{-1+\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}\})$. Define $X = L_1 \cup L_{-1} \cup (\bigcup_{n\geq 1}R_n)$, which is equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find the connected components of $X$. Also find points $a,b \in X$ in different connected components of $X$ such that there is no disconnection of $X = A\cup B$ with $a \in A$ and $b\in B$. [$X= A \cup B$ is a disconnection means $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets.]

My approach : For the first part, connected components of X are $L_1, L_{-1}, R_n; n\geq 1$.Clearly each of them are connected. Now to separate $R_n$ from $R_m$ with $n < m$, we take $\cup_{k \leq n} R_k = U \supseteq R_n$ and $U^c = V \supseteq R_m$ in $X$. Using subspace topology each of $U,V$ are open and they are also disjoint. Similarly we can separate $R_n$ from $L_i, i=1,2$ using $\cup_{k \leq n} R_k = U \supseteq R_n$ and $U^c = V \supseteq L_i$. And $L_1, L_{-1}$ are clearly disjoint.

For the second part, my guess is there is no such $a,b \in X$. As each connected components can be separated by the previous part. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $a$ on $L_1$ and any $b$ on $L_{-1}$, but say $a=(0,1)$ and $b=(0,-1)$ to be definite.
Assume $X=U\cup V$ with $U$ and $V$ open and disjoint, and $a\in U$ and $b\in V$.
Take $N$ such that for $n\ge N$ we have $(0,1-\frac1n)\in U$
and $(0,-1+\frac1n)\in V$ (these sequences converge to $a$ and $b$ respectively).
So for $n\ge N$ we have $R_n\cap U\neq\emptyset$ and $R_n\cap V\neq\emptyset$, which leads to a contradiction, as $R_n$ is connected.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you for correcting me. And for the first part, $L_1, L_{-1}, R_n$ are connected components, right?

Comment: Yes. See Example 115 in Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*